# Java Generics Question

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, queue, circular-buffer

Queue12 is an interface, QueueImp12 is an implementation of Queue12. So i'm trying to test my QueueImp12 but when i run it(it compiles) in eclipse my output gets terminated in console. I believe I created ringBuffer correctly. If my test looks fine, then something must be wrong with my implementation or eclipse. Thanks

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class QueueImpl12<T> implements Queue12<T> 
{

private int _size, _backIdx, _frontIdx;
private static final int _defaultCapacity = 128;
private T[] _ringBuffer;



public QueueImpl12(int capacity)
{
    _ringBuffer = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
    clear();    
}


public QueueImpl12()
{
    _ringBuffer = (T[]) new Object[_defaultCapacity];
    clear();
}

private int wrapIdx(int index)
{

    return index % capacity();
}



public void clear() 
{
    _backIdx = 0;
    _frontIdx = 0;
    _size = 0;

}

@Override
public int capacity() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _ringBuffer.length;
}

@Override
public int size() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _size;
}

@Override
public boolean enqueue(T o) 
{
    //add o to back of queue


    if(_ringBuffer.length == _size)
    {
        return false;
    }


       _ringBuffer[_backIdx] = o;
        _backIdx = wrapIdx(_backIdx + 1 );
        _size++;





    return true;
}

@Override
public T dequeue()
{
    if(_size == 0)  //empty list
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    T tempObj = _ringBuffer[_frontIdx];     //store frontIdx object
    _ringBuffer[_frontIdx] = null;          
    _frontIdx++;



    _size--;
    return tempObj;
}

@Override
public T peek() 
{

    return _ringBuffer[_frontIdx];
}

}




public class P3test  
{
public static<T> void main(String[] args) 
{
    final Queue12<T> ringBuffer = new QueueImpl12<T>();
    T o = (T) new String("this");
    ringBuffer.enqueue(o); //add element to the back
    ringBuffer.dequeue();  //remove/return element in the front

}
 }
```

Comment: This isn't valid Java code.  Please could you fix it!

Comment: Reformat your code. I is obvious that it won't compile now. Also main method is not a test, try JUint some day(TDD is so awesome).

Comment: Why are you casting a `String` to `T`?  That doesn't make any sense.  And where is `T` coming from?

Comment: If it compiles, the generics part should be fine. What exactly is the problem you see? Is it supposed to output anything?

Comment: i have 2 other classes, public interface Queue12<T>{..} andpublic class QueueImpl12<T> implements Queue12<T>{..} I wanted to test it through main somehow and wasn't sure what i could put in enqueue() to test it(going to start learning Junit/TDD now). i don't understand what type <T> is it just object type? since you can't put a string directly into enqueue, i thought making a string of type T would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 'terminated' you have been seeing lately is the expected behavior when your program finishes.

Put some `System.outs` or `asserts` to verify that your code runs (here it runs, with some awful cast warnings, but runs)

```
final Queue12<T> ringBuffer = new QueueImpl12<T>();
T o = (T) new String("this");
ringBuffer.enqueue(o); //add element to the back
System.out.println(ringBuffer.peek());//this should print 'this' in the console\
//assertEquals('this', ringBuffer.peek());
ringBuffer.dequeue();  //remove/return element in the front
```

Learn how to use generics and tests. And don't put generic argument in main function, is is useless there.